# sequence-pattern based algorithm with numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x

i would like if someone could help me find an algorithm that has this output.
left column is +=110 until (with)reaches 740 and the right column += 30(just for once) whenever the left column is equal to 740. take an example below:

```
80 70
190 70
300 70
410 70
520 70
630 70
740 70
80 100
190 100
300 100
410 100
520 100
630 100
740 100
80 130
190 130
300 130
410 130
520 130
630 130
740 130
```

Comment: left column: `80 + 110*(n%7)` right column: `70 + 30*(n//7)`

Comment: This has nothing to do with python, and it really isn't a question you should be asking on StackOverflow at all.

Comment: why is that? i just need an algorithm with this output in python . i dont care how. and ok i learned my mistake wont happen again. ill be more careful next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.x

```
for y in xrange( 70, 131, 30):
  for x in xrange( 80, 741, 110):
    print x, y
```

Python 3.x

```
for y in xrange( 70, 131, 30):
  for x in xrange( 80, 741, 110):
    print (x, y)
```

Comment: Nice and short! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many algorithms that can output this output. You didn't supply an input or any constraints

here's an example function that will output that output given the parameters -30, 40:

```
def weird_algo(n, m):
    for i in range(21):
        n = (n + 110) % 770
        m = m + 30 if n == 80 else m
        print n, m 

weird_algo(-30, 40)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 80
y = 70

while True:
    for i in range(0, 7):
        print(x,y)
        x = x + 110
    y = y + 30
    x = 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness of T33C's answer.

```
y=70
for p in range(3):
    x=80
    for i in range(7):
        print x,y
        x+=110

    y+=30
```

or:

```
for p in range(0,3):
y=70+30*p
for i in range(1,8):
    x=110*i-30
    print x,y
```

I am not really sure what are you up to, but there you go...